# Possible to use complex object types as keys in maps in Avro?

Tags: java, serialization, avro

Is it possible to use non Strings as keys in a Map with Avro?

I found this issue [AVRO-680](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-680?focusedCommentId=16985083&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16985083) which claims to have added non string key support, but I cannot find any examples, or work out from the patch how the new support works with a schema.

I would like to do something like this:

```
    "name": "aThing",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        { "name": "aMapOfThings", "type": {
             "type": "map", "keys": "MyKeyType", "values": "MyValueType"
           }
        }
    ]
```

Or in `avdl`:

```
  record aThing {
    map<MyKeyType, MyValueType> aMapOfThings = [:];
  }
```

Exactly like this question for protobuf: [Protobuf objects as Keys in Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729968/protobuf-objects-as-keys-in-maps)

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I'm also interested by this, and the comments on AVRO-680 are not very... clear...

Comment: Nope, sorry, still using smelling Strings...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the PR, it doesn't appear that this enhancement is actually designed to work with `SpecificRecord`. Looks like the code changes and tests are focused on `GenericRecord`, and deriving schema information via reflection from a Java class containing map(s) with non-string keys.

Below is an example of a schema derived from a POJO with a Map containing non-string keys (from [TestNonStringMapKeys.java](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/branch-1.9/lang/java/avro/src/test/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/TestNonStringMapKeys.java)). Notice it’s an array of records instead of a `map` type:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Company",
  "namespace" : "org.apache.avro.reflect",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "employees",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "Pair487429dd20c65898",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "key",
          "type" : {
            "type" : "record",
            "name" : "EmployeeId",
            "fields" : [ {
              "name" : "id",
              "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
              "default" : null
            } ]
          }
        }, {
          "name" : "value",
          "type" : {
            "type" : "record",
            "name" : "EmployeeInfo",
            "fields" : [ {
              "name" : "name",
              "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
              "default" : null
            } ]
          }
        } ]
      },
      "java-class" : "java.util.HashMap"
    } ],
    "default" : null
  } ]
}
```